# How to do inheritance @JsonFormat annotation in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I am working on JPA-Hibernate project. I have a date deserilaze problem but i have also solution in the below.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
private Date createdAt;
```

When I use @JsonFormat annotation with date, i solved the problem but i don't want to use this annotation every Date variable. I want to use MyDate annotation, as you can see below.

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@Inherited
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD,  ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
public @interface MyDate {

}
```

When i use @MyDate annotation, it doesn't work correctly. I keep failing like I've never used it. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you need:

The usage:

```
@MyDate    
private Date createdAt;
```

And the MyDate custom annotation class:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotationsInside;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
public @interface MyDate {}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Did you try Custom Jackson Annotation?

Check this out --> http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#highlighter_348118

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of the link in your answer, while still retaining the link. Link-only answers are not well tolerated here.